# Detect general lines in images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, convolution, edge-detection

I'm trying to find lines in an image, no matter how thin or thick they are.
I tried filtering the image with two filters:

```
[ -1 2 -1 ] [ -1 -1 -1 ]
[ -1 2 -1 ] [  2  2  2 ]
[ -1 2 -1 ] [ -1 -1 -1 ]
```

This gives me a good detection of vertical and horizontal lines, and then I average the two results and get nice detection of lines, but the problem is that this method varies with different thickness of lines (it just gets thin lines).
I wonder whether I can generalize this method or whether there exists more efficient way to do it.

One comment was to use the zero crossing of the first derivative, similar to detecting zero crossing for second derivative in edge detection, but I also don't know a way to implement this.

Comment: Line detection has been studied a lot in the literature. Did you do a search on scholar.google.com? What do you mean with "different thickness of lines"? Do you know up to what thickness it's still a line? At what thickness does it become a rectangle? You need to define these things before you start coding -- or deciding on a method.

Comment: Is skeletonization what you are looking for? Then you could use `bwmorph` :https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html

Comment: Another consideration to make is to detect one edge of a line, and then extrapolate to the entire object (however thick or wide it is). I would also look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo Since your comment motivates to consider a line as a rectangle when its thickness crosses a threshold I wonder whether you would advise to detect rectangles instead of lines in this image [line_grid](https://imgur.com/a/WrGtSjb) if I want to extract black thick lines which are 4 or 5 pixels thick?

Comment: @SKR: in that image, there is not much need for detection. Black pixels are lines, white pixels are not. What you probably are looking for is semantic segmentation, figuring out which pixels belong together in one line/arrow/box/etc. I don't have an immediate suggestion for you off the top of my head, but these things have been done before. A search in the scientific literature is always a good first start.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That's the keyword from someone experienced in image processing, I will look into that. On the contrary, black pixels also constitute symbols, curves, text, other types of lines in addition to what I want is black thick lines so image can't be segmented on the basis of pixel intensity. In brief, the output can be like this [only lines](https://imgur.com/iANzOYR.png).

Comment: @SKR: You could remove the thin black lines with a closing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo What about thin black curves? What about thick black symbols? Will they be retained? Can I use something like projection of rows and columns?

Comment: @SKR: A closing will remove anything that is thin, leaving only the ticker lines. You can specify the maximal width of things you want removed. Tweak that value so that only the thick lines remain.